# Unable to stop spawning an enemy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Okay so here's the dealio.

The code below is what I use to spawn a single enemy periodically in my horror game. He spawns at the window every 10 seconds, then every 6 seconds later, he enters the room and you're essentially dead already, because 5 seconds after that you get a lovely jumpscare. The moment the enemy shifts from the window to the bedroom is when I want the window enemy to stop spawning.

`EnemyShipTimer` is the timer that spawns the enemy.

`enemyTimer` is the timer that counts how long the enemy has been at
   the window, and then in the room.

In the main file, I've attempted to get rid of the enemy a number of ways, to no effect.

So `function gtfo` is my latest attempt at removing the enemy, by trying to stop the spawning from the class file itself. It still hasn't worked. Maybe I need to somehow remove the class file from my game, but I have no idea how. Please help! ;A;

PS, `countClick` counts how many clicks you've done to make the enemy go away, although when I make him go away, room enemy still spawns :c

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class EnemyShip extends MovieClip

{
    private var clickCount:int = 0;
    private var enemyShipTimer:Timer;
    private var enemyTimer:Timer;



    public function EnemyShip()
    {

        this.x = 900;
        this.y = 214;

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, countclick);
        addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, gtfo);

    }



    function gtfo(e:TimerEvent):void{
        if (enemyTimer.currentCount==5)
        enemyShipTimer.stop();
        stage.removeChild(this);
    }

    function addClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        clickCount = clickCount + 1;
        trace("Clickage : " + clickCount);

    }


    function countclick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        if (clickCount ==4)
        {
            stage.removeChild(this);

        }
    }

}

}
```

The following is the relevant main timeline code that may be clashing with the code (I have updated the package class as per @Karma 's helpful instructions c: though the enemy still spawns; I think what the problem is now is that the timer functions clash with timer functions I've put in my main timeline, and I attempted to sort of move them into the package class but I don't know how to add the necessary movieclips so that I won't get *access of undefined property* errors so I separated the two once more

`enemy` is the window spawning enemy.

`mosnta` is the room spawning enemy.

`sod` is the screen of death (game over screen) which does not play at all.

```
var enemyShipTimer:Timer;

function sendEnemy(e:Event)
{

var enemy = new EnemyShip();
stage.addChild(enemy);
var enemytimer = new Timer (1000, count);
enemytimer.start();
enemyShipTimer = new Timer(10000);
enemyShipTimer.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemy);
enemyShipTimer.start();

enemytimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdowndesu);
function countdowndesu(e:Event):void{
if (enemytimer.currentCount>5){
    trace("ur ded");
    enemytimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdowndesu);
    mosnta.visible=true;
    enemy.visible=false;


if (enemytimer.currentCount==8){
    sod.visible=true;
    sod.gotoAndPlay(2);
}



}
}
}
```

Comment: why 2 listeners for click? do it in one. also dont assume that stage exists:) check if not null. also if you check equality it may be possible taht you click more than 4 or 5 times before the timer will do test, change to `clickCount > 5` and see if your code will trigger anything.

Comment: Your timers are not created properly. You need to instantiate a Timer object, then add the TimerEvent listener onto the timer, and then call the start() method. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: @Karma Could you provide an example of a correctly created timer? I don't know how to do what you're suggesting ;A;

Answer (score 0):

Not really understanding the dynamics of how your game works, but here's an altered version of your code with working Timers. Maybe this will help you figure out how to fix your issues

```
package 
{    
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class EnemyShip extends MovieClip    
    {
        private var clickCount:int = 0;
        private var enemyShipTimer:Timer;
        private var enemyTimer:Timer;

        public function EnemyShip()
        {        
            this.x = 900;
            this.y = 214;

            //only need one click handler
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);

            //Instantiate Timers
            enemyShipTimer = new Timer(10000); //10 seconds
            enemyTimer = new Timer(6000); //6 seconds

            //add TimerEvent listeners onto Timer Objects
            enemyShipTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, gtfo);
            enemyTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, enemyTimerHandler);

            //Start the timers
            enemyShipTimer.start();
            enemyTimer.start();
        }       

        //This gets called every 10 seconds
        private function gtfo(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace("enemy spawns at window");
            if (enemyTimer.currentCount == 5) {
                 enemyShipTimer.stop();
                 stage.removeChild(this);
            }
        }

        //This gets called every 6 seconds
        private function enemyTimerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace("enemy moves to room");
        }

        private function addClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            clickCount ++;
            trace("Clickage : " + clickCount);
            if (clickCount == 4)
            {
                stage.removeChild(this);

            }    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, though the enemy still spawns; I think what the problem is now is that the timer functions clash with timer functions I've put in my main timeline, and I attempted to sort of move them into the package class but I don't know how to add the necessary movieclips so that I won't get _access of undefined property_ errors

I have updated my post with the timeline code though if it helps!

Comment: should I update the main question with the updated package code? ;0;